# How can I change the background color of an <option> element in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm having trouble setting the background color (and text color) for the options in a `<select>` list in Google Chrome.

Seems to work fine in Firefox:

[image: Screen shot 2012-02-08 at 11.57.38 AM.png]

But not in Google Chrome:

Closed:

[image]

Open:

[image: Screen shot 2012-02-08 at 11.59.00 AM.png]

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        select
        {
            background:yellow!important;
        }
        option
        {
            background:red!important;
        }
        .c1
        {
            background-color:green!important;
            color:red!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<select>
    <option class="c1">nice long option name</option>
    <option class="c2">nice long option name</option>
    <option class="c3">nice long option name</option>
    <option class="c4">nice long option name</option>
    <option class="c5">nice long option name</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

I wonder if Google Chrome is using it's own elements or perhaps elements of the host operating system to render the select box and perhaps this is why it doesn't work? Perhaps it's a good thing because those colors look fairly horrendous, but it would be nice if Chrome offered a little bit more control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:
select { -webkit-appearance: none; }

Maybe that should help you.

If not.. than probably Chrome does not support it.

Comment: i've selected this as right because of the second part "Chrome does not support it"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, -webkit-appearance do the job well.

But, don not apply this rule on select element, assign it to option/optgroup:

```
option, optgroup { -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

This solves "white text on whitebackground" in Chrome on Ubuntu.

Hope, this help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this issue before as well CWD. Seeing as Browser's have a default value with Forms and Form Elements sometimes you need to override the Browsers Setting via JavaScript/jQuery.

Check out this link: This may help with styling.

http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements

Comment: hmm, looks like one option is to "build" your own select box with `divs` but that's not exactly what i was hoping for. http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In general, trying to style  and  elements is more trouble than it's worth. Cross browser support is horrendous. You will generally end up using a JS solution. If you're targeting one specific browser, you might be okay, but I'd just let browsers render  and  elements the way you want.

That said, if you're looking for a good JS solution to this, I've used [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and found it worked great. It will swap out your desired  element with a div and li items, which you can style to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

This has been an ongoing issue with sites using a dark theme.  I found that applying this rule in the main css file solves the issue for me:

select { -webkit -appearance:none }

Hope it helps someone.